# Generar columnas en jasper report en Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en Java para generar un listado en Jasper Report, desde un fichero Json , el cual puede cambiar de estructura es decir ,, cambiar de columnas y numero de ellas ... o sea puede imprimir un listado de clientes y la misma aplicacion un listado de articulos con sus datos de cabecera y pie de informe....
Despues de mucho he logrado descifrar todo e ir generando la aplicacion hasta el punto donde utilizando el comando "fastReportBuilder.addColumn" .. voy creando las columnas ... el codigo es asi ...

```js
package javaapplication11;

import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.DynamicReport;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.FastReportBuilder;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reportejav {
   
    public static DynamicReport buildReport() throws ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FastReportBuilder fastReportBuilder = new FastReportBuilder();
        int contador = 0 ;
         String cadena;
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        FileReader f = new FileReader("c:/tools/estructura.Json");
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
            contador = contador + 1;
            System.out.println(b.readLine());
              
        fastReportBuilder.addColumn(cadena, cadena, String.class.getName(), 50);
           }
        fastReportBuilder.setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true).setUseFullPageWidth(true);
          return fastReportBuilder.build();
      }

 }
```

El problema es que al compilarlo me da ...:

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/list/UnmodifiableList


null
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.entities.DJGroup.getFooterVariables(DJGroup.java:178)
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.DynamicReportBuilder.build(DynamicReportBuilder.java:261)
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.FastReportBuilder.build(FastReportBuilder.java:102)
 at javaapplication11.Reportejav.buildReport(Reportejav.java:53)
 at javaapplication11.JavaApplication11.main(JavaApplication11.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.list.UnmodifiableList
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 5 more
C:\tools\jasperreports-5.0.1\JavaApplication11\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1040: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\tools\jasperreports-5.0.1\JavaApplication11\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 20
```

y ya no sigue.. este programa es llamado desde otro .Java.. pero da el problema en la linea que dice .:

```js
     return fastReportBuilder.build();
```

Alguien me puede explicar que pasa o porque da ese error.. os lo agradeceria ....

Gracias a todos!!!

Comment: Te falta la libreria de apache commons

Comment: ok lo miro pero entonces porque no se queja ... estoy programando en NETBEANS.. y si no tengo una libreria se queja..  de todas formas lo miro y te digo .. gracias por responder !!!!

Comment: he montado esa libreria y sigue dando el mismo error ... seguimos viendo ..

Comment: Perdona, es commons-collections la que necesitas.

Comment: efectivamente.. pero resulta que encuentro la ... collections4  .. y no la ..collections .. y entonces el compilador sigue buscando la collections .. y no se quien llama a esa libreria

Comment: No uses la versión 4 collections pues esta usa otros paquetes y por eso te mapea. Usa una anterior.

Comment: ya me di cuenta de ese problema .. muchas gracias .. esto de las librerias es casi como una loteria .....

Comment: ya estoy bastante adelantado , pero tengo otro problema, las columnas que se generan a traves de addcolumns no aparecen en el listado, ... es comomsi no creara las columnas..... alguna idea???